# How to provide error message to a custom error page without inheritance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, error-handling

I've got a passage like this in the *Web.config* files.

```
<system.webServer> 
  ...
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Home/Err/404?message=Not found" responseMode="Redirect" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Home/Err/500?message=Total poof" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

This works as supposed to except that I'd like to have the messages to be automatically provided, as is the case with the default ones, including the stack trace and inner exceptions.

The thing is that I don't intercept the errors but rather let the default filter handle that for me. Is there a simpler way than [inheriting *HandleErrorAttribute*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31441906/1525840)?

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
  filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
  ...
}
```

Comment: you can use Application_Error in global.asax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since exceptions can come from various layers and i need to log the exception and route to the correct error page, I've handled the exceptions in global.asax.

```
    void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        AppEventSource.Log.Error(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl, GetUserName(HttpContext.Current.User), exception.Message, HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress);
        Server.ClearError();

        if (exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Error/401");
        }
        else {
            //generic error
            Response.Redirect("~/Error");
        }
    }
```